PDFBox 3.2: Missing Bounding Box Error in PAC for Image Tag in PDF/UA
I'm trying to create a PDF/UA document using PDFBox 3.2, and I’ve followed the solution suggested by @Tilman Hausherr in this Stack Overflow post. I managed to tag both text elements and images, and the image appears correctly tagged in PAC. However, I’m still getting an error in PAC indicating a missing bounding box for the image.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far to resolve this issue:
Marked Content for Rectangle: I created marked content for the image’s rectangle and added it to the document. (No success, as the error persisted).
Adding COSName.BBOX to Figure Structure Element: I added a new item COSName.BBOX with a Rectangle(x, y, width, height) to the figure structure element. (Resulted in a corrupted PDF).
Adding COSName.BBOX to Figure Reference: I added a new item with COSName.BBOX in the figure reference, similar to step 2. (Also resulted in a corrupted PDF).

Despite these efforts, I still don’t see anything in the structure representing the bounding box when I attempt to convert my PDF to PDF/UA. Any guidance on what I might be missing to correctly define the bounding box for the image in PDFBox 3.2 would be greatly appreciated! here is Code für Image creation and Tagging :
COSDictionary markedContentDictionary3 = new COSDictionary();
        markedContentDictionary3.setInt(COSName.MCID, mcidCounter + 2);
        markedContentDictionary3.setString(COSName.ALT, "Alternate Image Description");

        PDMarkedContentReference mcr3 = new PDMarkedContentReference();
        mcr3.setMCID(mcidCounter + 2);

        //COSDictionary markedContentDictionary4 = new COSDictionary();
        //markedContentDictionary4.setInt(COSName.MCID, mcidCounter + 3);
        //PDMarkedContentReference mcr4 = new PDMarkedContentReference();
        //mcr4.setMCID(mcidCounter + 3);

        contentStream.beginMarkedContent(COSName.IMAGE, PDPropertyList.create(markedContentDictionary3));
        contentStream.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height);
        contentStream.endMarkedContent();
        // Schließen des Inhaltsstroms
        contentStream.close();

        PDStructureElement figureElement = new PDStructureElement(StandardStructureTypes.Figure, documentElement);
        figureElement.setPage(page);
        figureElement.setAlternateDescription("Dieses Bild zeigt: <dein_Tag_oder_Beschriftung>");

        figureElement.appendKid(mcr3);

        documentElement.appendKid(figureElement);



I need a working file to compare (I probably have one, but this will take time). The only thing I do remember is that the image needs its own StructParent value which must also be in the parent tree (as a dictionary, not as an array child).

assign a number to the image:
image.setStructParent(structParentCounter + 1);

include the figure element in the parent tree, and assign it an attribute
PDStructureElement figureElement = new PDStructureElement(StandardStructureTypes.Figure, documentElement);
PDLayoutAttributeObject attributeObject = new PDLayoutAttributeObject();
attributeObject.setBBox(new PDRectangle(x, y, width, height));
attributeObject.setPlacement(PDLayoutAttributeObject.PLACEMENT_BLOCK);
figureElement.addAttribute(attributeObject);
figureElement.setPage(page);
figureElement.setAlternateDescription("Dieses Bild zeigt: <dein_Tag_oder_Beschriftung>");
PDMarkedContentReference mcr3 = new PDMarkedContentReference();
mcr3.setMCID(mcidCounter + 2);
figureElement.appendKid(mcr3);
documentElement.appendKid(figureElement);
parentTreeMap.put(structParentCounter + 1, figureElement);
// add to the array from SO 79126664, the 0-based index = MCID
ar.add(null); // because you have an MCID "1" about which I know nothing about
ar.add(figureElement); 

also don't forget to call
structureTreeRoot.setParentTreeNextKey()

with the highest value plus 1.

Thank you so much for the quick response! and I appreciate your support. concerning  warning "Possibly inappropriate use of a figure structure element". I tried to convert the generated PDF in this website link and the only change I saw , was a strange NoStruct Elment added after DokumentElemnt, see image in question. I created the same Structure but warning still there.

I don't really understand you, what I did was to modify my last answer (because your code isn't self-working) to add an image and then added the code in the answer. Maybe include the file that you created and maybe I can tell where this "NonStruct" is coming from or what's wrong. Also weird that your figure is first in the list from that image but has MCID 2. It should be last. My updated file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dhROwTrjk_vrzkMGCyWTQDlnyAcW06p3/view?usp=sharing

I've made a modification and the warning is gone, all it took was to read https://taggedpdf.com/508-pdf-help-center/possibly-inappropriate-use-of-a-structure-element/ and set the placement to BLOCK.

Thank you for your guidance and references! Apologies for any confusion my new structure may have caused. I’ve since reorganized the structure elements and adjusted the MCID, thinking that could solve the warning. After applying your latest modifications, everything is now functioning smoothly without any errors or warnings. I really appreciate your support and the resources you provided—thank you again!
